# How to get sitemap using a controller, and update old one

Tags: magento-1.9, php, sitemaps

I created **sitemap.xml** by controller using core **observer.php** file which is inbuilt in magento.

Now I want *sitemap.xml* on screen by `hitting my controller ur`l, and also want to update the ***old sitemap.xml***
my controller ->

**IndexController.php** :

```
public function indexAction(){
$collection = Mage::getModel('sitemap/sitemap')->getCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $sitemap) {
    try {

      $sitemap->generateXml();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below solution:

```
$data =array();
$data['sitemap_path']= '/';
$data['sitemap_filename'] = 'sitemap.xml';
$model = Mage::getModel('sitemap/sitemap');
 $path = rtrim($data['sitemap_path'], '\\/')
                      . DS . $data['sitemap_filename'];

$validator = Mage::getModel('core/file_validator_availablePath');
/** @var $helper Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Catalog */
$helper = Mage::helper('adminhtml/catalog');
$validator->setPaths($helper->getSitemapValidPaths());
if ($validator->isValid($path)) {
$model->setData($data);
$model->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');

$collection = Mage::getModel('sitemap/sitemap')->getCollection();
/* @var $collection Mage_Sitemap_Model_Mysql4_Sitemap_Collection */
foreach ($collection as $sitemap) {
    /* @var $sitemap Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap */

    try {
        $sitemap->generateXml();

        if($sitemap->getSitemapPath() == '/') {
            $realPath = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/'.$sitemap->getSitemapFilename();
        } else {
            $realPath = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/' . $sitemap->getSitemapPath().$sitemap->getSitemapFilename();
        }

        if(file_exists($realPath)) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($realPath);
            echo $xml->asXML();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
```